# Clay strips sculpting brush cutting inward in certain areas and cutting outward in others

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I am making an axe and am using the clay strips brush to make marks in the axe but when I draw over the part of the axe that is carved out the clay strip digs into the mesh instead of adding to it. I have attached images showing the issue. Does anyone know why>?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the normals of that section flipped?

Comment: yes you should check the normals but I wonder if there are not bugs sometimes

Comment: how wide is that axe? one person had a similar problem recently and the problem was pretty simple, the brush was too big and it was sculpting backside of the object with the front side as well, it can cause a problem... look at the top panel, there are brush settings, try to activate "Front face only" option and try again if it helps

Comment: I changed to front face only and that worked! Thank you very much!